# How to access all [labels] in json array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm having a problem with json array data using PHP. I use a `foreach` to loop through the data, and only the first list of [labels] is captured. Everything for array index 1 and greater is not captured.

In the included json, `$keywordfilters` will echo:

"Google, intelligence, press release, leadership" from index 0.

"leadership, press release" will not be captured from index 1.

Please help.

**PHP:**

```
// Keyword Filters
echo '<div class="sub-nav" role="menu">';

// Loop to get all keywords for filtering
$recordcounter = 0;
foreach($json->items as $jsondata){

    $keywordfilters = '<strong style="margin: 0 3px 3px; padding: 3px 10px 3px 0; display: block;">Filter:</strong> <a href="#" role="menuitem" class="active" style="margin: 0 3px 3px; padding: 3px 10px 3px 0; display: block; float: left;">All</a>';

    $keywordcounter = 0;
    foreach($jsondata->labels as $keywordlabels){
        //foreach($keywordlabels as $labels){
            //strtolower,strtoupper,ucfirst,lcfirst
            $keywordfilters .= '<a href="#" role="menuitem" style="margin: 0 3px 3px; padding: 3px 10px 3px 0; display: block; float: left;">' . ucfirst($keywordlabels) . '</a>';

            $keywordcounter++;
        //}
    }

    $recordcounter++;
}

echo $keywordfilters;

echo '</div>';
```

**JSON:**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [kind] => blogger#postList
    [nextPageToken] => CgkIChiA48Lo_igQg4DLkK7p2Kke
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [kind] => blogger#post
                    [id] => a123456789
                    [content] => TESTESTEST

                    [author] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => sro5t7y4nte76vtcmhsazsdffsdy
                            [displayName] => MyDisplayName
                            [url] => https://www.blogger.com/profile/a1234567890
                            [image] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [url] => //lh6.googleusercontent.com/-3HzpopblNls/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAADC8/YJsx2U5TQ9I/s35-c/photo.jpg
                                )

                        )

                    [labels] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Google
                            [1] => intelligence
                            [2] => press release
                            [3] => leadership
                        )

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [kind] => blogger#post
                    [id] => b123456789
                    [content] => TESTESTEST

                    [author] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => sro5t7y4nte76vtcmhsazsdffsdy
                            [displayName] => MyDisplayName
                            [url] => https://www.blogger.com/profile/a1234567890
                            [image] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [url] => //lh6.googleusercontent.com/-3Hz321blBls/AAABBBABACAAAI/AACCC76AADC8/YJsx2U5TQ9I/s35-c/photo.jpg
                                )

                        )

                    [labels] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => leadership
                            [1] => press release
                        )

                )
        )

    [etag] => "rone8ryudb8ditsvmp8re8dt/oprdnyt75GRFYTUiofygjlhft8y"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Hope this will help you out.
The problem was this

```
$keywordfilters = '<strong style="margin: 0 3px 3px; padding: 3px 10px 3px 0; display: block;">Filter:</strong> <a href="#" role="menuitem" class="active" style="margin: 0 3px 3px; padding: 3px 10px 3px 0; display: block; float: left;">All</a>';
```

You were using this statement within the `foreach` loop which overrides it everytime.

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string = '{ "kind" :"blogger#postList", "nextPageToken" :"CgkIChiA48Lo_igQg4DLkK7p2Kke", "items" : { "0" : { "kind" :"blogger#post", "id" :"a123456789", "content" :"TESTESTEST", "author" : { "id" :"sro5t7y4nte76vtcmhsazsdffsdy", "displayName" :"MyDisplayName", "url" :"https://www.blogger.com/profile/a1234567890", "image" : { "url" :"//lh6.googleusercontent.com/-3HzpopblNls/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAADC8/YJsx2U5TQ9I/s35-c/photo.jpg"}}, "labels" : { "0" :"Google", "1" :"intelligence", "2" :"press release", "3" :"leadership"}}, "1" : { "kind" :"blogger#post", "id" :"b123456789", "content" :"TESTESTEST", "author" : { "id" :"sro5t7y4nte76vtcmhsazsdffsdy", "displayName" :"MyDisplayName", "url" :"https://www.blogger.com/profile/a1234567890", "image" : { "url" :"//lh6.googleusercontent.com/-3Hz321blBls/AAABBBABACAAAI/AACCC76AADC8/YJsx2U5TQ9I/s35-c/photo.jpg"}}, "labels" : { "0" :"leadership", "1" :"press release"}}}, "etag" :"rone8ryudb8ditsvmp8re8dt/oprdnyt75GRFYTUiofygjlhft8y" }';
$json=json_decode($string);
echo '<div class="sub-nav" role="menu">';

// Loop to get all keywords for filtering
$recordcounter = 0;
$keywordfilters = '<strong style="margin: 0 3px 3px; padding: 3px 10px 3px 0; display: block;">Filter:</strong> <a href="#" role="menuitem" class="active" style="margin: 0 3px 3px; padding: 3px 10px 3px 0; display: block; float: left;">All</a>';
foreach($json->items as $jsondata){


    $keywordcounter = 0;
    foreach($jsondata->labels as $keywordlabels){
        //foreach($keywordlabels as $labels){
            //strtolower,strtoupper,ucfirst,lcfirst
            $keywordfilters .= '<a href="#" role="menuitem" style="margin: 0 3px 3px; padding: 3px 10px 3px 0; display: block; float: left;">' . ucfirst($keywordlabels) . '</a>';

            $keywordcounter++;
        //}
    }

    $recordcounter++;
}

echo $keywordfilters;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In every outer loop:
$keywordfilters is being reset.

```
    $keywordfilters = '<strong style="margin: 0 3px 3px; padding: 3px 
    10px 3px 0; display: block;">Filter:</strong> <a href="#" 
    role="menuitem" class="active" style="margin: 0 3px 3px; padding: 
    3px 10px 3px 0; display: block; float: left;">All</a>';
```

You need to use .= to append previous array's data.

```
    $keywordfilters .= '<strong style...
```

Comment: It will generate `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable`. You need to initialize `$keywordfilters = '';` before the `foreach` loop.

Comment: No, It wont generate notice since the loop will run as it has data. Anyways its a good practice to initialise variables. It will throw notice only when it doesn't enter the loop.

Comment: Concatenation `.=` operator inside the loop will throw a notice. [see example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d8fac8917ca391bc3a0db112986cc878bbcfec2d)

Comment: Thank you for the solution.